# Complexity of map coloring

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

This is a follow up question to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82838/4-color-theorem-on-surfaces) one.

I've recently read that for planar maps, it is possible to color these in $O(N^2)$, $N$ being that number of vertices [1].
What are the computational complexities to get face colorings for maps on other compact surfaces?

[1] Neil Robertson, Daniel P. Sanders, Paul Seymour, and Robin Thomas.
Efficiently four-coloring planar graphs. In Proc. 28th Symposium on
Theory of Computing, pages 571-575. ACM, 1996.

Comment: I presume you've already seen [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-97-01926-0)?

Comment: Not yet. Great reference, thanks.