# Graphs on surfaces other than the plane that are still $4$-colorable...?

Tags: graph-theory

> In graph theory, the [Heawood conjecture or Ringel–Youngs theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heawood_conjecture) gives a lower bound for the number of colors that are necessary for graph coloring on a surface of a given genus:

I've [learned](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/82840/19341) that,

> it takes 
>   $$\left\lfloor \frac{7 + \sqrt{49 - 24 \chi}}{2} \right\rfloor$$
>   colors except for the Klein bottle where it takes $6$, where $\chi$ is the Euler characteristic of the surface.

But the thing is that I'm interested in graphs on surfaces other than the plane that are still $4$-colorable. 
How could an example look like?
Or does $4$-colorability imply that it can be drawn in the plane?

Comment: It's pretty obvious that any graph that can be drawn on the plane can also be drawn on any other surface, so there are plenty of $4$-colourable graphs on say the Klein bottle.

Comment: Or do you mean you want a $4$-colourable graph that *can't* be drawn on the plane, and the stuff about other surfaces is irrelevant?

Comment: Any surface that forbids $K_5$ minors will force all graphs to be at most $4$-colorable.  Any surface that doesn't forbid $K_5$ minors will allow $K_5$ to be drawn, which is $5$-colorable.  Any graph with a $K_{3,3}$ minor without a $K_5$ minor will be $4$-colorable (at most) and cannot be drawn on a plane.

Comment: If the latter, then bisecting every edge of any graph gives you a topologically equivalent graph that's $2$-colourable.

Comment: @chris I mean graphs that can't be drawn on the plane.

Comment: @andrew, this sounds like I'm looking for graphs with a $K_{3,3}$ minor on a surface that forbids $K_5$ minors. Do you know some example or tell how to get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you get a $3$-colourable map on the torus: Wrap up a chessboard to a torus and replace the vertices with small faces (just to make the map regular). With an odd (e.g. $9\times 9$) chessboard, the same construction gives you a $3$-colourable graph of the projective plane and from a $9\times 8$ (or other even/odd combination) you get a $3$-colourable map on the Klein bottle. These maps are not planar (unless the chessboard was too small) and give examples of maps that are even $3$-colourable. Some suitable modification of the maps is easily made to make a fourth colour necessary.